# Django version downgraded when I install third party Django package

Tags: python, django

When we upgrade Django version this two packages prompted incompatible

```
Installing collected packages: django
  Attempting uninstall: django
    Found existing installation: Django 3.1.6
    Uninstalling Django-3.1.6:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-3.1.6
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the foll
owing dependency conflicts.
django-helpdesk 0.3.4 requires Django<4,>=2.2, but you have django 4.0.4 which is incompatible.
django-celery-beat 2.2.1 requires Django<4.0,>=2.2, but you have django 4.0.4 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed django-4.0.4
```

When we try to upgrade packages(django-helpdesk) django core version was downgraded. Is this not a bug?

```
pip install django-helpdesk --upgrade
--------
--------
--------
Installing collected packages: Django
  Attempting uninstall: Django
    Found existing installation: Django 4.0.4
    Uninstalling Django-4.0.4:
      Successfully uninstalled Django-4.0.4
Successfully installed Django-3.2.13
```

Please help me

Comment: make sure your project running with it's own  virtual environment

Answer (score 1):

Not an bug, as helpdesk requires **Django 2.2 LTS or 3.2 LTS**.
So it automatically set it for you when you tried to install/upgrade it.

But as your package showing incompatible there, you can do:
`pip install django==(<4.0,>=2.2)`

for example: `pip install django==3.2`
I hope this would work for you!